# Swift Reference to a Dictionary Key and Value Without Knowing Key

Tags: dictionary, swift

I have an Array of Dictionaries defined as

```
var users = [[String:String]]()
```

The Dictionary inside the array is a simple username + yes/no flag
     [[1stUser: Y], [2ndUser: N], [3rdUser: N]]

In my TableView cell configuration, I defined

```
let userRecord = users[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
```

and need to 
assign cell.textlabel.text = username (the key of the dictionary)

check flag (Y/N) and if Yes > cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

In the example above, I should get a checkmark next to 1stUser only.

The question is how to refer to the dictionary keys ('1stUser', '2nduser' etc.) without knowing them in advance and check values (Y/N)?  All the Swift dictionary examples I have seen assume we know the actual key to retrieve its value (e.g users["1stUser"] does not help as I do not know in advance that 1stUser has a Y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always know your dictionary keys. If you don't, you're structuring your data wrong - unknown data should always be in the value of a dictionary, never the key.

Consider instead using a dictionary with two keys: "username" and "flag".

---

Sample code:

```
var users = [[String:String]]()

users.append(["username" : "Aaron", "flag" : "yes"])
users.append(["username" : "AspiringDeveloper", "flag" : "yes"])

let userRecord = users[1]

let username = userRecord["username"]!
let flag = userRecord["flag"]!
```

Alternatively, you could build a basic class and avoid the dictionaries entirely:

```
class User {
    let username: String
    let flag: Bool

    init(username:String, flag:Bool) {
        self.username = username
        self.flag = flag
    }
}

var users = [User]()

users.append(User(username: "Aaron", flag: true))
users.append(User(username: "AspiringDeveloper", flag: true))

let userRecord = users[1]

let username = userRecord.username
let flag = userRecord.flag
```

Comment: I can't agree with that. There are innumerable situations where a dictionary is used for data validation, for instance to check user input. It is perfectly customary to lookup a dictionary for an unknown key.

Comment: Why would you need a dictionary with an unknown key to check user input? The OP is quite clearly storing a *value* in the *key*.

Comment: No. The OP has a simple relation implemented by a dictionary with a Username as the key (actually the primary key of the relation) and a Boolean attribute Y/N as the value. This is a perfectly reasonable construct for a small table. The OP is just wondering how to enumerate the entries in the table and check their Y/N value. By the way, there is nothing like a dictionary with two keys, AFAIK.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Dictionaries can have more than one key: `let dictionaryWithTwoKeys = ["username" : "Yves Daoust", "flag" : "yes"]`

Comment: You'd better say two entries or two records, these are key+value pairs. I don't see how that would help solve the OP's question.

Comment: The OP's question is "how to refer to the dictionary keys without knowing them in advance"; in my proposed solution they are known in advance.

Comment: Aaron/Yves: I am truly grateful for the exchange of ideas and your specific examples. I am planning to test the sample codes and advise. In response to other queries, the dictionary can contain multiple Users with Y or no users with Y. I am also intrigued by the suggestion to use Class and will try it too. Thanks to everyone for their sincere advice.

Comment: Aaron: It worked! Your suggestion of a dictionary with 2 keys.
when username and flag are added to dictionary:

self.dict.append(["username" : username, "flag" : flag])

when displaying the tableView cell:

if self.dict.count > indexPath.row {

let userRecord = self.dict[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel.text = userRecord["username"]!
if userRecord["flag"]! == "Y" {
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark } } else { cell.textLabel.text = "Loading..”}

Thank You!

Comment: I am yet to learn how to present code in gray boxes, apologies for the unformatted post above!    self.dict.append(["username" : username, "flag" : flag])

Comment: "If you don't, you're structuring your data wrong"  [citation needed]

Comment: @TylerA. Why do you think it's called a "key"? (I don't mean that sarcastically.)

Comment: The statement about knowing your keys is indeed wrong. Just think about storing custom, user-provided attributes for some objects. You cannot know those in advance. Actually I’d say the opposite is true: If you know the keys, the dictionary is the wrong data structure. Use a struct or a class instead.

Comment: If the user is providing the keys and values then the user is responsible for knowing the keys. All I’m saying is if you have to iterate through the keys of a dictionary, you’re losing the main benefit of the dictionary structure, which is quick lookup of a value from a key.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @AaronBrager answer, but...

If you are sure the dictionary has at least one value, and no more than one value, you can

```
let dict = ["user1":"yes"]

// retrieve the key and the value
let (key, val) = dict[dict.startIndex] // -> key == "user1", val == "yes"

// retrieve the key
let key = dict.keys.first! // -> key == "user1"
```

So, let's convert `[[String:String]]` to `[(name:String,flag:Bool)]`

```
let users:[[String:String]] = [["1stUser": "Y"], ["2ndUser": "N"], ["3rdUser": "N"]]

let usersModified = users.map { dict -> (name:String, flag:Bool) in
    let (key, val) = dict[dict.startIndex]
    return (
        name: key,
        flag: val == "Y" ? true : false
    )
}
```

By doing that you can simply:

```
let user = usersModified[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel.text = user.name
cell.accessoryType = user.flag ? .Checkmark : .None
```

Comment: Thanks rintaro. The dictionary does have multiple users with different Y/Ns. As indicated, Aaron suggestion of a dictionary with 2 keys/recs did solve the problem. My tableview now shows all users, with correct checkmarks next to the users with Y flags. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on a dictionary using:

```
for (key, value) in myDictionary {
   // here use key and value
}
```

Comment: This will get the OP the answer but it is a poor way to store this data.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about storing data. Anyway sometimes it can be useful to enumerate all the keys in a dictionary (and to know how to do it).

Comment: Thanks Valfer. I did study the for (key, value) in Apple's Swift language reference, but it did not quite solve my issue (wanting to display a table where a cell with a user name can have a checkmark or not, based on the dictionary entries.). As indicated prior, Aaron suggestion of 2 keys/records solved the problem. My tableView now shows the correct checkmark next to the users with Y.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the key(s) in advance, there is no other way than enumerating all (key, value) pairs (like @valfer said) and test the flag value. A dictionary will not support queries such as "report all entries having a True value".

Your problem statement is not clear about whether there is always exactly one True flag or not. If yes, you can stop the scan as soon as you found it.

Comment: Thanks Yves. I learned a lot from my first post in StackOverflow and should have expanded on the problem statement to indicate the dictionary can contain multiple users with varied Y/Ns or no users at all (as it's built prior in the program according to other conditions). Thank you again for your input.