# How to find a particular key value with name in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am having Json data which I am retrieving from model class in which I need to find if the key value pair `title` having word starting with `Discount` for example if I find key value pair starting with `Discount` I need to set the particular table view cell label as `Discount` how to find it from key value pairs can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Here is my model class data

```
struct TotalPriceSegments {

    let code : String?
    let title : String?
    let value : Double?

    init(json: [String:Any]) {

        self.code = json["code"] as? String
        self.title = json["title"] as? String
        self.value = json["value"] as? Double

    }
}
```

Here is table view code

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checkout", for: indexPath) as! CheckoutTableViewCell
            let array = totalPriceModel?.totalSegments[indexPath.row]
            cell.titleLabel.text = array?.title
            let total = doubleToStringDecimalPlacesWithDouble(number: Double((array?.value)!), numberOfDecimalPlaces: 2)
            cell.valueLabel.text = (String(describing:("$ \(total)")))
            return cell
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Reference to a Dictionary Key and Value Without Knowing Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989443/swift-reference-to-a-dictionary-key-and-value-without-knowing-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cellForRow method add such check:

```
if array?.title.hasPrefix("Discount") {
  cell.titleLabel.text = "Discount"
}
```